# is it compulsory to use __del__ method in all custom created classes , is del command a destructor

Tags: python, destructor

Is it compulsory to use `__del__` method in all custom created classes? Is the del command a destructor?

Comment: Don't implement `__del__` unless you know that you _really_ need it. If you have to ask "Do I need `__del__` in this class?", you probably don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `del` merely deletes the name. If the object referenced by that name has other references, it will continue to exist. The `__del__` method is not guaranteed to be called even when there are no references to the object.

If you need predictable object lifespan and the ability to clean up after yourself, use a context manager and the `with` statement.

Answer (score 2):

No and no.

Good description [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

You really never have to worry about `__del__`, but it is a destructor and will get called by the garbage collector.

`del` is not a destructor, it just deletes a reference. When all the references are gone, the garbage collector may eventually call `__del__`.